# AWS to host existing java application

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services

I have j2ee application which developed using following sw and tools.
MySQL , java ,tomcat and apache load balancer.

We have been successfully deploying these in dedicated and virtual (vmware) environments with Ubuntu and other Linux O/S.
Now we have a requirement to deploy the application in AWS , what approach I should take. Any thought ,
It’s  complex J2EE web application and I’m thinking  to use AWS to host our web application as just another deployment environment after buying Linux O/S  virtual machines.

At present we use apache load balancer to load balance multiple tomcat nodes using mod_proxy_ajp also apache load balancer used to break ssl communication .

Applicate any comments. Thanks

Comment: You can use all those with aws as well. Just start some EC2 instances. Or you use ELB for loadbalancing, RDS for sql and Beanstalk instead of a custom tomcat server. "what approach I should take" can not be answered without exact requirements.

Comment: Thanks zapl, This is what i was thinking too. What meant is that i want to start with sw and tools what i use so we can deploy the application with minimum development , then we can start think about using native AWS tools like ELB . Am i right two say i can treat each AWS instance as seperate virtual machines and deploy the application same as we do in Vmware (of course with some tweaks) .

Comment: You should consider one of the automatic deployment tools. This would help to deploy test environments and redeploy production if necessary.

Comment: @csf yes you can treat each EC2 instance as a separate virtual machine, because that is exactly what they are.

Comment: can someone say why there's -1 in this question , is it that bad ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just treat EC2 servers the same as the other Linux VMs you have been using and there will be no real difference in your deployment process.

If you want to take more advantage of AWS services you could look into the following:

- RDS MySQL (or Aurora) instead of installing MySQL on an EC2 instance.
- Elastic Load Balancer instead of Apache